# Compare two text files and write the differences to text file

Tags: powershell, compare, compareobject

I want to compare 2 text files and output the difference in another text file.

```
$Location = "c:\temp\z.txt"
compare-object (get-content c:\temp\hostname_old.txt) (get-content c:\temp\hostname_new.txt) | format-list | Out-File $Location
```

hostname_old.txt

```
server02
server05
server04
server06
server01
```

hostname_new.txt

```
server04
server01
server02
```

Results

```
InputObject   : server05
SideIndicator : <=

InputObject   : server06
SideIndicator : <=
```

This is what I want : (get rid of both InputObject and SideIndicator)

```
server05
server06
```

Note: A related problem where one input file has duplicate entries is the subject of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54573751/45375).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [-PassThru parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object):

```
compare-object (get-content c:\temp\hostname_old.txt) (get-content c:\temp\hostname_new.txt) -PassThru | Out-File $Location
```

does exactly what you want.

Comment: This solution doesn't care about duplicates. Each new line of text is considered unique. So, a duplicate in the "new" file, will be copied to out, unless it's also duplicated in the "old" file.

Answer (score 0):

*Update*: [Palle Due's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54572164/45375) offers the best solution.
This answer may still be of interest for contrasting member-access enumeration with pipeline use, a discussion of output formatting, and contrasting `Out-File` with `Set-Content`.

---

In PSv3+ you can simply **use [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)** to extract the `.InputObject` values:

```sh
PS> (Compare-Object (Get-Content old.txt) (Get-Content new.txt)).InputObject
server05
server06
```

Note:

- Member-access enumeration is convenient and fast, but at the expense of memory consumption, which can be a problem with very large collections (not here). The output from `Compare-Object` must be collected in memory *as a whole* in an array (`[object[]]`), and, similarly, the `.InputObject` property values are returned as an array.
- For slower, but memory-friendly streaming (one-by-one processing), use the *pipeline* with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`, as in [TobyU's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571733/45375).

Re **saving to a file**: piping to `Out-File $location` (or, more succinctly, using output redirection: `> $location`) is sufficient - no need for `Format-List`.

In general, note that the purpose of the `Format-*` cmdlets is to produce output for *display*, not for programmatic processing and persistence.

That said, **`Out-File` / `>` (effectively) uses the `Format-*` cmdlets behind the scenes to produce a string representation** of the input objects, just like the default console output, which is why it's **not the right command for persisting arbitrary input objects.**

Use of **`Out-File` / `>` with *strings* is safe, however**, because they are output as-is. By contrast, even numbers are problematic if they have decimal places, because they are stringified with the current culture's decimal separator (e.g., `,` rather than `.` in some cultures).

**If your input objects are *strings*, you can alternatively use `Set-Content`, which is faster than `Out-File` / `>`**, but the caveat is that in Windows PowerShell the character encoding used by default differs: `Out-File` / `>` produces UTF-16LE files by default, whereas `Set-Content` uses the legacy system locale's "ANSI" code page (typically, a single-byte 8-bit encoding such as Windows-1252).
By contrast, in PowerShell *Core* both cmdlets produce BOM-less UTF-8.

Note that `Set-Content`, unlike `Out-File`, stringifies non-string objects simply by calling the `.ToString()` method on them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for `Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject`

```
compare-object (get-content c:\temp\hostname_old.txt) (get-content c:\temp\hostname_new.txt) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject | Out-File $Location
```

Please note, that you cannot use `format-list` in the `Pipeline` before writing data into a file.

Comment: Solid solution.
Note that you _can_ use the `Format-*` cmdlets with `Out-File` / `>` (but not with `Set-Content`). In fact, `Out-File` / `>` (effectively) uses the `Format-*` cmdlets behind the scenes to produce a string representation of the input objects.
That said, unless the input objects are strings, the resulting representation is suitable for human consumption only, not as a stable format for programmatic processing.