# Compare two text files with duplicates and write the distinct differences to text file

Tags: powershell, compare, compareobject

I want to compare 2 text files and output the difference in another text file.

```
compare-object (get-content c:\temp\hostname_old.txt) (get-content c:\temp\hostname_new.txt) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject | Out-File $Location
```

hostname_old.txt

```
server02
server05
server04
server06
server01
```

hostname_new.txt (has duplicate names)

```
server04
server01
server02
server04
server02
```

Result:

```
server04
server02
server05
server06
```

Note how `server04` and `server02` are present in this list of differences, even though they're present in *both* input files.

This is what I want:

```
server05
server06
```

Comment: not really fancy, but something like that `| Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Select-Object -Unique` to eliminate the duplicates before comparing:

```
compare-object -PassThru `
  (get-content c:\temp\hostname_old.txt) `
  (get-content c:\temp\hostname_new.txt | Select-Object -Unique)
```

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54572164/45375) to your previous question, `-PassThru` is used to pass out the differing lines directly, without the `[pscustomobject]` wrappers (that indicate the source set of the difference via their `.SideIndicator` property) that `Compare-Object` outputs by default.